# OOP Visibility, in general and specifically in PHP

Tags: php, oop, visibility

This is probably a general OOP question, but I'm using PHP, so if it exists in general, I'd like to know, but give me warning if you know it's missing or warped in PHP.

Is it possible for a class that instantiates an object of another class (which it is not extending) to set the visibility of the instantiated object's properties?

Example:

```
Class Widget {

    public $property1;
    public $property2;
    public $property3;
  }

Class ClockMaker {

  public function getWidget() {

      $this -> widget = new Widget();
      $this -> widget -> property1 = "special stuff";
   }
}

$my_clock = new ClockMaker();
$my_clock -> getWidget();
$my_clock -> widget -> property2 = "my tweak";  // Totally fine and expected...
$my_clock -> widget -> property1 = "my stuff";  // Should throw an error...
```

As far as I understand, if I set property1 to protected, ClockMaker won't be able to set the value.  But if as it stands right now, $my_clock can have it's way with the widget object.

Anyway to prevent the property from being set once it's been set?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't change  any property and getWidget is never called. It will create `widget` property in your `$my_clock` object, and then create another object from an empty value (if you enable strict errors, you'll see a strict notice). Declare `widget` in your class:

```
Class ClockMaker {
  private $widget;

  public function getWidget() {

      $this -> widget = new Widget();
      $this -> widget -> property1 = "special stuff";
   }
}
```

Comment: The lack of getWidget() was an oversight, and the lack of property change is because I don't know what it would look like (hence the question).  The first error has been corrected.   In your example, `$my_clock` wouldn't have any access to widget, is that right?  I want (in fact, need) to allow some properties to be public and writable, while others protected but visible.  But I feel a step closer with your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: This way, each time you get a widget from the getWidget method, the previous widget gets overwritten. If you want to create a new widget, I suggest naming it createWidget for readability. If you just want to return the widget, don't create a new instance, but create the instance in the constructor and return that one.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use get_ and set_ methods? Seems like it should solve your problems. These are also best practices in OOP for playing object properties outside of the object itself.

```
class Widget {
  private $foo;

  public function setFoo($val) { $this->foo = $val; )
  public function getFoo() { return $this->foo; )
}
```

You also asked, "Anyway to prevent the property from being set once it's been set?"

```
class Widget {
  private $foo;

  public function setFoo($val) {
    if (!isset($this->foo)) {
      $this->foo = $val;
    }
    //If you want to throw an error or something just use an else clause here.
  }
  public function getFoo() { return $this->foo; )
}

$w = new Widget();
$w->setFoo('Foooooo');
echo $w->getFoo(); //Foooooo
$w->setFoo('Magic.');
echo $w->getFoo(); //Foooooo
```

If you're looking for something else, could you please make the question more specific? :)

Answer (score 0):

If a class declares something public then it's public.  If you don't intend for the class member to be public then it should be declared protected or private.  Unless you resort to introspection and reflection (which is strongly discouraged because it usually leads to spaghetti code and is death to performance), then the only way you can change a member's visibility is to inherit the class in a subclass and redeclare the member with the new visibility.  When you're doing this you're only able to make a member more visible then it was before (A private member can become public, but not the other way around).

Generally speaking, you usually don't want to make properties (variables) public, because if you do then outside agents can change the state of the class at will without any kind of control, and you can quickly get into a big mess.  In your example, you need to make property2 protected or private if you don't want outside agents to change it.

However, if outside agents still need access to it, then you should provide a getter and setter method for this job. A getter returns the value of the property, and a setter lets it get changed in a controlled way.  Getters and setters let you do such things as make a property read only, or implement lazy-initialization (meaning that if the class needs to do some expensive operation to 
initialize a property such as a DB lookup, then it can be deferred until the value is actually needed)

```
class Widget ()
{
    protected $property2;

    public function getProperty2 ()
    {
        // This is an example of lazy initialization in a getter.
        if ($this -> property2 === NULL)
        {
            $this -> property2 = 'Value has been initialized'
        }
        return ($this -> property2);
    }

    public function setProperty2 ($newProp)
    {
        // Example of input validation
        if {($newProp !== NULL) && ($newProp !== 'This is an illegal value!')}
        {
            $this -> property2 = $newProp;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException;
        }
        return ($this);
    }
}
```

If you need property2 to be read-only, then just omit the setter altogether (or make it non-public if you still need its validation functionality inside your class). As the property can't be directly accessed from outside, your getter and setter let you have total control over what goes into the property and how it comes out again.

Incidentally, in most cases it's considered bad practice for a class to initialize the classes it depends on.  It makes unit testing more difficult (as you can't test a class that initializes its own dependencies in isolation) and can make your code less clear (as a dependency hidden away inside the class isn't immediately obvious to someone using your class with only the public API as a guide). It also robs you of some flexibility, because if a class initializes its own dependant objects, then you can't substitute them for other objects that provide the same interface.  There are exceptions to the rule (such as generating exceptions when errors occur), but as a general rule, a class shouldn't contain a `new` statement inside it and shouldn't pull objects in with Registry or Singleton classes.  They should also avoid static calls to other classes.

It's considered a better idea to use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) instead.

```
Class Clockmaker 
{
    protected $widget;

    public function __construct (Widget $newWidget)
    {
        $this -> widget = $newWidget;
    }
}
```

Why is this better?  The answer is now it's obvious that your ClockMaker class depends on a Widget class, so it improves readability.  It also means that you can use any object that's a subclass of Widget in place of Widget itself without problems.  Should you unit test, you can replace Widget with a subclass where all the methods return the same value all the time, so you can now test your ClockMaker class in isolation (if an error occurs during the test, you can be sure the error is in ClockMaker.  With the ClockMaker initializing Widget itself, you don't know if a failed test is due to a bug in Clockmaker, or a bug in Widget).